# Telethon - Enter Telegram verification code via GUI

Tags: javascript, python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to edit my code so that when a user creates a new session name in the input, it will ask for the verification code via the GUI and not the terminal, so I can have a functional application.

```
import traceback, asyncio, sys, time, csv
from quart import Quart, request, jsonify, send_file 
import pandas as pd
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty, PeerChannel, Channel 
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.users import GetUsersRequest
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from flask_cors import CORS
from datetime import datetime, timezone

app = Quart(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.after_request
async def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
    return response

client = None

@app.route('/init_client', methods=['POST'])
async def init_telegram_client():
    global client

    print('init_telegram_client hit')
    data = await request.get_json()

    session_name = data.get('session_name')
    api_id = data.get('api_id')
    api_hash = data.get('api_hash')
    phone_number = data.get('phone_number')
    code = data.get('code')  # Use .get to avoid KeyError if 'code' is not provided
    password = data.get('password')  # Use .get to avoid KeyError if 'password' is not provided

    client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
    await client.connect()
    print("Client Created")

    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        print(f"Sending code request to {phone_number}...")
        await client.send_code_request(phone_number)
        try:
            if code:
                await client.sign_in(phone_number, code)
                print("Sending code...")
            elif password:
                await client.sign_in(password=password)
        except SessionPasswordNeededError:
            return jsonify({'status': 'password_needed'})
        
        return jsonify({'status': 'connected'})
    
    return jsonify({'status': 'already_connected'})


async def get_entity_from_channel_name(client, channel_name):
    try:
        entity = await client.get_entity(channel_name)
    except ValueError as e:
        entity = channel_name
    try:
        my_channel = entity
        if hasattr(my_channel, 'title'):  # add this check
            return my_channel
        else:
            print(f'Entity retrieved for channel_name={channel_name} is not a Channel or Chat. Got {my_channel.__class__.__name__} instead.')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error getting entity for channel_name={channel_name}: {e}')

async def fetch_messages(client, my_channel, start_date, end_date):

    start_date_timestamp = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
    end_date_timestamp = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()

    offset_id = 0
    limit = 0
    all_messages = []
    total_messages = 0
    while True:
        print("Current Offset ID is:", offset_id, "; Total Messages:", total_messages)

        history = await client(GetHistoryRequest(
            peer=my_channel,
            offset_id=offset_id,
            offset_date=None,
            add_offset=0,
            limit=limit,
            max_id=0,
            min_id=0,
            hash=0
        ))

        if not history.messages:
            break
        messages = history.messages

        for message in messages:
            print(f'Message date: {message.date}')
            if message.message:
                message_timestamp = message.date.timestamp()
                if message_timestamp < start_date_timestamp:
                    return all_messages
                elif start_date_timestamp <= message_timestamp <= end_date_timestamp:
                    #print(f'Message timestamp: {message_timestamp}')
                    all_messages.append(message.to_dict())
        offset_id = messages[len(messages) - 1].id
        total_messages = len(all_messages)
        print(f'\nTotal messages: {total_messages}')
    return all_messages

@app.route('/scrape_channel', methods=['POST'])
async def scrape_channel():
    data = await request.get_json()
    channel_names = data['channel_name'].split(',')
    api_id = data.get('api_id')
    api_hash = data.get('api_hash')
    phone_number = data.get('phone_number')

    session_name = data.get('session_name')

    start_date = data.get('start_date')
    end_date = data.get('end_date')

    code = data.get('code')  # Use .get to avoid KeyError if 'code' is not provided
    password = data.get('password')  # Use .get to avoid KeyError if 'password' is not provided

    global client
    
    if client is None:
        client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
        await client.connect()

    all_messages = []

    for channel_name in channel_names:

        my_channel = await get_entity_from_channel_name(client, channel_name)
        messages = await fetch_messages(client, my_channel, start_date, end_date)
        for message in messages:
            message['channel'] = channel_name
            all_messages.append(message)

    df = pd.DataFrame(all_messages)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    df['message'] = df['message'].dropna()
    print(f'\nThis is how many messages you should expect to find: {len(df)}')

    if ',' in data['channel_name']:
        df.to_csv('scraped_messages.csv', encoding='utf-8', columns=['date', 'message', 'channel'], index=False)
    else:
        df.to_csv(channel_names[0] + '_messages.csv', encoding='utf-8', columns=['date', 'message'], index=False)
    
    return jsonify({"status": "success"})

@app.route('/get_csv/<channel_name>', methods=['GET'])
async def get_csv(channel_name):
    csv_file = 'scraped_messages.csv' if ',' in channel_name else f"{channel_name}_messages.csv"
    return await send_file(csv_file, mimetype='text/csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, port=5002)
```

This is my JavaScript for the GUI.

```
function getApiDetails() {
    const api_id = parseInt(document.getElementById('api_id_input').value);
    const api_hash = document.getElementById('api_hash_input').value;
    const phone_number = document.getElementById('phone_number_input').value;
    const session_name = document.getElementById('session_name_input').value;
    //const code = document.getElementById('code').value;
    //const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    
    return {api_id, api_hash, phone_number, session_name};
}

document.getElementById('api_details_button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('api_details_button clicked');
    const apiDetails = getApiDetails();
    
    // Convert the apiDetails object to a JSON string and save it to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('apiDetails', JSON.stringify(apiDetails));
    console.log('apiDetails saved to localStorage');
    console.log(apiDetails)

    const statusElement = document.getElementById('api_details_status')
    statusElement.textContent = 'API details saved';
    statusElement.style.display = 'block';

    setTimeout(function() {
        statusElement.style.display = 'none';  // Hide the message after 3 seconds
    }, 4000);

    document.getElementById('clear_api_details_button').style.display = 'block';

});

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');

    document.getElementById('clear_api_details_button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Clear the saved API details
        localStorage.removeItem('apiDetails');
        console.log('API details cleared from localStorage');

        document.getElementById('api_id_input').value = '';
        document.getElementById('api_hash_input').value = '';
        document.getElementById('phone_number_input').value = '';
        document.getElementById('session_name_input').value = '';

        console.log('localStorage:', localStorage);

        // Update the status

        const statusElement = document.getElementById('api_details_status');
        statusElement.textContent = 'API details cleared';
        statusElement.style.display = 'block';
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            statusElement.style.display = 'none';
        }, 4000);
            
        document.getElementById('clear_api_details_button').style.display = 'none';
    });

    const savedApiDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('apiDetails'));
    if (savedApiDetails) {
        document.getElementById('api_id_input').value = savedApiDetails.api_id;
        document.getElementById('api_hash_input').value = savedApiDetails.api_hash;
        document.getElementById('phone_number_input').value = savedApiDetails.phone_number;
        document.getElementById('session_name_input').value = savedApiDetails.session_name;
        console.log('Loaded API details from localStorage');

        document.getElementById('clear_api_details_button').style.display = 'block';
    }
});


document.getElementById('Scrape_messages').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const channelName = document.getElementById('channel_name').value;
    const startDate = document.getElementById('start_date').value;
    const endDate = document.getElementById('end_date').value;
    console.log(startDate);
    console.log(endDate);

    const apiDetails = getApiDetails();

    fetch('http://localhost:5002/init_client', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(apiDetails)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.status === 'code_needed') {
            const code = prompt('Enter the verification code sent to your Telegram');
            if (code) {
                apiDetails.code = code;
                this.click();
            }
        } else if (data.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Successfully connected to Telegram');

            // Update the status
            document.getElementById('status').textContent = 'Scraping messages...';
            
            fetch('http://localhost:5002/scrape_channel', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    channel_name: channelName,
                    start_date: startDate,
                    end_date: endDate,
                    ...apiDetails
                })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById('status').textContent = 'Scraping done. You can now download the messages.';
                document.getElementById('Download_messages').disabled = false;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                document.getElementById('status').textContent = 'An error occurred while scraping. Please try again.';
            });
        } 
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});



document.getElementById('Download_messages').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const channelName = document.getElementById('channel_name').value;
    const filename = channelName.includes(',') ? 'scraped_messages.csv' : `${channelName}_messages.csv`;

    fetch(`http://localhost:5002/get_csv/${channelName}`)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        a.click();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});


var settings = document.getElementById("settings");
var closebtn = document.getElementById("closebtn");
var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");

console.log(sidebar);  // Should log the sidebar element, not null
console.log(closebtn);  // Should log the closebtn element, not null

settings.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("close button clicked");  
  sidebar.style.width = "250px";
});

closebtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("close button clicked");  
  sidebar.style.width = "0";
});
```

The code gives me several problems:

1. The server-side Python prints this error:

**telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.AuthKeyUnregisteredError: The key is not registered in the system (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest)**

2: It also never prompts the user to input the verification code via the GUI.